# How to remove a user defined language in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I just added a user defined language in notepad++ by importing an XML. Now, I want to remove this language from the notepad++ Language menu. How can I do that?

If I use the Settings->Languages menu in Notepad++, then I can only remove the languages listed by default in Notepad++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't an English version of Notepad++ but I hope you'll understand:

1. Select Menu "Language"
2. "Define language"
3. Select the language you want to remove from the drop-down box
4. Click on "Delete"

Answer (score 5):

If the languages reappear when Notepad++ is restarted, find and delete the `userDefineLang.xml` file. Depending on your installation, this is likely found in the `%appdata%\Notepad++` folder.

This is what I was forced to do and it deleted the two offending languages that kept reappearing.

Comment: Thank you, this was driving me insane. I would delete the language and it would reappear every time I restarted the application.

Comment: Thank you! They say the relevant bug is solved, but I don't know.  Keeps re-appearing.
https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/8101

Answer (score 4):

Here is animated GIF that shows how to remove User Defined Language in Notepad++. (Version 7.5.9)

[image]

**Note** - It is reported that in a newer version of Notepad++, the deleted language reappears after notepad++ restart. If you experienced this issue, please find and delete the userDefineLang.xml file. Depending on your installation, this is likely found in the %appdata%\Notepad++ folder. (Credit to @CrazyMoniker)

Comment: Very nice GIF, but in Notepad++ 7.8.7, this does not work. The language is "removed" but reappears when Notepad++ is restarted. I can make changes to the language, and they are saved - for example I can rename it to "Bad Language" and change the extension to ".bad-lang" and this will be preserved when Notepad++ is restarted. However, removal is not preserved.

Comment: This doesn't work in Notepad++ v8.1.9.  After removal, it comes back after being restarted.

Comment: @endolith please follow the steps in below comment, and you will be able to delete the language without it reappearing. Thanks.

Comment: Also does not work for NP++ 8.4.4 .... (it is not permanently removed!)